# Why do I get 31 Dec 1969 as my last modified filename using filemtime in php?

Tags: php, datetime, function

I am newbie to php and so please do not mind me asking this question but am really getting confused as to why `filemtime(filename.txt)`gives me as 31 Dec 1969 as my last modified time ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This probably means your file was not found, either :

- because it doesn't exist
- or because it's not in the currect directory
- or because you didn't quote its name -- you didn't ^^

1st january 1970 is the date of time "zero" ; and `filemtime` returns `false` when there is a problem...

So, 31 Dec 1969 is the date/time of zero... According to your locale, I suppose ; I myself, with this code :

```
$filemtime = filemtime(filename.txt);
$formated = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $filemtime);
var_dump($filemtime, $formated);
```

get this output :

```
boolean false
string '1970-01-01 01:00:00' (length=19)
```

false because the file doesnt' exist, and `1970-01-01` at `01:00` because of my locale *(I'm in France, at UTC+1 hour)*

And note I also get a couple of notices and warnings :

- `Notice: Use of undefined constant filename - assumed 'filename'`
- `Notice: Use of undefined constant txt - assumed 'txt'`
- `Warning: filemtime() [function.filemtime]: stat failed for filenametxt`

Do you have any of those ?

If no : are `error_reporting` and/or `display_errors` enabled ?

Comment: @Pascal: Thank you Pascal for the detailed answer. I am getting warning mentioning stat failed for filename and my error_reporting is enabled

Not sure why filemtime is not getting my file as if I echo it than I get the filename but wrong modified time as 31st Dec, still wondering why it is happening that way.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it by making the file path absolute by concatenating complete physical path before `$filename` as file last modified date by `filemtime($physical_path.$filename)` and file size by `filesize($physical_path.$file)`.

Answer (score 1):

January 1, 1970 0:00 is the start of the Unix epoch. Thus, a timestamp of 0, which is the result of a failed filemtime operation, together with (probably) a DST issue, is December 31, 1969. You need to fix your filemtime operation, for example (if your example is not just pseudo-code) by adding quotes to the filename:

```
filemtime ("filename.txt");
```

Comment: It's actually a return value of `-1`, hence why it's in 1969.

Comment: Nope, that's what I first thought too, but filemtime() returns false (=0) on failure. The explanation must have something to do with daylight savings time.

Comment: It's at the tail end of 1969, adjusted by the number of hours and minutes your timezone is away from UTC, since filemtime converts to the local timezone.

Answer (score 0):

You get this if filemtime cannot find the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use

```
$t = filemtime(filename.txt);
```

At a minimum, use something like

```
$t = filemtime("filename.txt");
```