# File Last Modified Date not correct

Tags: php

I have a function that displays a list of all the files upload to a specific webpage. I also want to display the date that the file was last modified, but it is displaying all of the dates as December 31 1969 19:00:00. How do I amend this function so that it displays the correct date? (it's in the echo statement at the end):

```
<?php     
    foreach($phpfiles as $phpfile)
    {
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($phpfile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if ($imageFileType == "pdf") {
            $faicon = 'fa fa-file-pdf-o'; 
        } else if ($imageFileType == "doc" || $imageFileType == "docx") {
            $faicon = 'fa fa-file-word-o'; 
        } else if ($imageFileType == "xls" || $imageFileType == "xlsx") {
            $faicon = 'fa fa-file-excel-o'; 
        } else if ($imageFileType == "ppt" || $imageFileType == "pptx") {
            $faicon = 'fa fa-file-powerpoint-o'; 
        } else if ($imageFileType == "mp4") {
            $faicon = 'fa fa-file-video-o'; 
        } else if ($imageFileType == "jpg" || $imageFileType == "png" || $imageFileType == "gif" || $imageFileType == "bmp") {
            $faicon = 'fa fa-file-image-o'; 
        } else {
            $faicon = 'fa fa-file-text-o'; 
        }
        if ($server_name <> ""){ 
            $phpfile = "http://". $server_name . '/' .$phpfile;
        }
        echo "<span class='$faicon w3-large'></span>&emsp;&emsp;<a href='$phpfile' class='w3-medium' target='_blank'>".substr(basename($phpfile),-1*strlen(basename($phpfile))+strlen($id)+1)."</a>&nbsp;". date("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($phpfile));
    }
?>
```

[image]

Comment: have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853575/why-do-i-get-31-dec-1969-as-my-last-modified-filename-using-filemtime-in-php

Comment: I hadn't, but after reading it I do not get any errors as suggested. Also, my files are populating, so I know that it is finding the file.

Comment: what this will echo ```file_exists($phpfile)``` ? Asking since according to your current code $phpfile may be valid location so pathinfo() will work correctly (it doent check existence of the file, simply parse string as i remember), but nothing will be in the filesystem

Comment: What is $phpfiles? You loop that array to $phpfile then you edit the value of $phpfile with `$phpfile = "http://". $server_name . '/' .$phpfile;` what happens if you filemtime **before** you edit the variable?

Comment: @Andreas setting a variable with filetime before editing the phpfile variable did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in comments above:

The problem is that you overwrite the variable $phpfile with this code:

```
if ($server_name <> ""){ 
    $phpfile = "http://". $server_name . '/' .$phpfile;
}
```

If you instead create a variable with the filemtime date before you change string $phpfile then you can echo it later.

```
$date = date("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($phpfile));
if ($server_name <> ""){ 
    $phpfile = "http://". $server_name . '/' .$phpfile;
}
echo "<span class='$faicon w3-large'></span>&emsp;&emsp;<a href='$phpfile' class='w3-medium' target='_blank'>".substr(basename($phpfile),-1*strlen(basename($phpfile))+strlen($id)+1)."</a>&nbsp;". $date;
```